# Windows 7 update files deleted, now new updates cannot be installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

A friend of mine has "cleaned up" his Windows folder and deleted "unused update files".

He tried to update Windows last weekend, but the update crashed again and again.

It seems he simply deleted stuff in \SoftwareDistribution\Download manually. I'm not sure if he deleted anything else in \SoftwareDistribution.

Repairing the OS via the DVD did not work and he does not want a wipe/new installation (he'd lose some old software that way).

I've tried renaming the folder C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download to prompt Windows to create a new one and download the deleted updates, but this did not work either.

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: What says the event log? What is the crash code? Or codes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he deleted something else. Anyway, what does "crash" actually mean in this context?

Comment: Windows Update produces Error 800B0100. I've tried the steps suggested here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956702 but it keeps coming up.

Comment: Roll the system back using a restoration point.  You can also attempt to use SFC to repair the damage, but he might have to accept, his actions can only be solved by reinstalling the operating system.

Comment: Have you deleted the updates by following the certain procedure ?? Read this article to know more about how to Uninstall and Reinstall Windows Updates http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-remove-and-reinstall-all-windows-updates/

Comment: First off - thank you all for the tips and the help. I'm absolutely certain that he deleted other files, the log was flooded with errors. Deleting the update history seemed to work at first, but the same error kept coming up. There were no restoration points to work with either. When I learned that the software he did not want to lose was not old but new and very pirated I told him that I had done all I could to help him, and he finally agreed to a reinstall.